# How break cycle for with if else statement in django template

Tags: django

I read if else statement in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/)
but i don't understand my case.
I have photos list, i want render image if is COVER else i want render static image.
This my code

```
{% for x in listing.photos.all %}
{% if x.photo_tipo == 'COVER' %}
<img src="{{ x.get_thumb }}" alt="">
{% else %}
<img src="{% static 'images/about/1.jpg' %}" alt="">
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Result is: an image if x.photo == 'COVER' and a static image for every other photo in the list.
I would like to get only one result if the declaration is true or only one static image if it is false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this in the template. Add some logic somewhere that gives you the photo with that type directly if it exists. A good way would be with a method on the Listing model:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    ...
    def cover_photo(self):
        return self.photos.filter(photo_tipo='COVER').first()
```

Now your template could be:

```
{% with photo as listing.cover_photo %}
    {% if photo %}
    <img src="{{ photo.get_thumb }}" alt="">
    {% else %}
    <img src="{% static 'images/about/1.jpg' %}" alt="">
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but i don't know to apply it in my case.

Comment: I write method 
def cover_photo(self):
        return Photo.objects.filter(photo_tipo ='COVER').first()
in my Photo model. But photos doesn't display in my ListView

Comment: No that goes in the model of whatever `listing` is, ie the thing that has the relationship to Photo.

Comment: I put in template 
{% with photo as listing.photos.cover_photo %}
{% if photo %}
<img src="{{ photo.get_thumb }}" alt="">
{% else %}
<img src="{% static 'images/about/1.jpg' %}" alt="">
{% endif %}
 {% endwith %}
It display only static image